# Contradiction involving the Cantor Set and Baire Category Theorem

Tags: general-topology, baire-category, cantor-set

I was given a "proof" that contradicts the Baire Category Theorem and I can't figure out why it doesn't work.

> Let $C$ be the Cantor set in $[0,1]$. Then $[0,1]\setminus C$ is a disjoint union of countable open intervals. Take a point from each of these sets and call the set of such points $A$. Define $X = C \cup A$, which is closed, so it is a complete metric space and thus the Baire Category Theorem holds in $X$. Then $A$ is open in $X$, since it is the intersection of $X$ and the complement of $C$. Additionally, $A$ is countable, so it is first category. Then $A$ is an open set of first category, which contradicts the Baire Category Theorem.

I suspect that $X$ is not actually closed ($A$ certainly isn't closed), but I am having trouble proving that is the case i.e. finding a limit point of $X$ not contained in $X$. I think the way to do that would be to construct a sequence using both $C$ and $A$ whose limit isn't in $A$ or $C$, but I am not sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: Let $[0,1]\setminus C=\cup F$ where each $f\in F$ is a non-empty open interval. For each $f\in F$ choose $\psi(f)\in f$ and let $A=\{\psi(f): f\in F\}. $ Then $[0,1]\setminus (C\cup A) $ $=\cup_{f\in F}[\;(\inf(f),\psi(f)) \cup (\psi(f),\sup(f))\;]$ is open. So $X=C\cup A$  $is$ closed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each point of $A$ is an isolated point of $X$, so $A$ is not the union of countably many nowhere dense sets in $X$: if $x\in A$, $\operatorname{cl}_X\{x\}$ has non-empty interior, namely, itself. Thus, $A$ is not first category in $X$.

Comment: Of course! I totally missed that.